# Mandate type *not* abstract in ocaml module type

Tags: ocaml

I want to define a module type with a `type t`. Any implementer of the `type` must therefore choose a `type t`. Is there any way to guarantee from the module `type` definition that this `type t` *not* be abstract. So say I had this definition in my mli file:

```
module type TYP = sig
  type t
  val f: t->unit
end
module M:TYP
```

With this module type, anybody who wanted to call `M.f` would be out of luck, since the `type t` is abstract, so there's no way of generating it. Of course, I could do this

```
module type TYP = sig
  type t
  val f: t->unit
end
module M:TYP with type t=int
```

But is there any way to "demand" that the `type t` not be abstract, so that any implementer must expose it?

Comment: I think the demand would come from the ultimate utility of the module with the module signature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is not possible. But you can demand a user to provide you a constructor, like this:

```
module type T : sig
   type t
   val create : unit -> t
   val f : t -> unit
end
```